# Get records from a table where the field 'day' is the same

Tags: mysql

I have a table called itinerary which has a list of ports , arrivals and departures etc

The day field indicates the day of the itinerary 1,2,3 etc

the table is like this

id, day, order, port, port_id, type, arrive, depart, cruise_id

I want to select each record where the cruise_id has more than one stop on a given day so I can update the order field so the stops on that day are listed in the right order...

e.g.

cruise_id 25 has two itinerary records for day 3

I just want to select those records and then I can do an update query, but I'm struggling to select them correctly

I think I'm totally off track with this...

```
 SELECT * , COUNT( DAY ) FROM itinerary GROUP BY cruise_id LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HAVING` and a `GROUP BY` and this should be all right:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) AS c
FROM itinerary
GROUP BY cruise_id, day
HAVING c > 1
```